# Is multiplying by 0.0000001 the same as dividing by 10000000?

Tags: java, floating-accuracy

In Java, is multiplying a double by 0.0000001 the same as dividing it by 10000000? My intuition is that there could be a difference because 0.0000001 cannot be represented exactly in a double.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No it's not the same for the reason you mentioned. Here's an example:

```
double x = 894913.3;
System.out.println(x * 0.0000001);    // prints 0.08949133
System.out.println(x / 10000000);     // prints 0.08949133000000001
```

Using a `BigDecimal`, we can see the difference between the two values:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.0000001));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal((double)10000000));
```

Ouput:

```
9.99999999999999954748111825886258685613938723690807819366455078125E-8
10000000
```

Comment: Ok, so where is the explanation?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov In the question. :)

Comment: The intuition in the question is the correct explanation. The closest double to 0.0000001 is 9.99999999999999954748111825886258685613938723690807819366455078125E-8.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only not the same because of the double representation but also if you multiply an integer by a double the result is a double. If you devide an integer by an integer, the result is an integer:

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println(i*0.0000001);
System.out.println(i/10000000);
```

prints

```
1.0E-7
0
```

Comment: The question asked about multiplying a double or dividing "it", I assume the same double.

Comment: Oops, you are correct. Should I keep my answer anyways or remove it?